# Why does my Flutter page sometimes not render completely in release version?

Tags: flutter, dart

## Problem

I have a Flutter app with a log in page. When I run the app in debug mode, the log in page is rendered properly when the app is opened. But when I build a apk release of the app with `flutter build apk --release`, install it and then open the app in the emulator, the login page is not rendered properly. See screenshots below.

### Running in debug mode, properly rendered:

[image]

### Running the release build, not completely rendered:

[image]

## Code

### Login page code:

```
// @dart=2.9

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';
// import 'package:myapp/helpers/FCMHelper.dart';
import 'package:myapp/helpers/SecureStorageHelper.dart';
import 'package:myapp/helpers/SharedPreferencesHelper.dart';
import 'package:myapp/models/LoginModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:myapp/models/Token.dart';
import 'package:myapp/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:myapp/models/UserAndTokenModel.dart';
import 'package:myapp/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:myapp/pages/reset_password_page.dart';
import 'package:swipedetector/swipedetector.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

import '../home_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  String loginResponse = "";
  SecureStorageHelper secureStorage;
  bool rememberMe;
  bool isFirstBuild;
  bool isKeyboardVisible = false;
  double displayWidth;
  FocusNode emailFocus;
  FocusNode passwordFocus;
  KeyboardVisibilityController keyboardVisibilityController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    init();
    delayedInit();
    super.initState();
  }

  init() {
    emailFocus = new FocusNode();
    passwordFocus = new FocusNode();
    displayWidth = 1;
    rememberMe = false;
    addKeyBoardListener();
    secureStorage = new SecureStorageHelper();
  }

  delayedInit() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      getReemberMe();
      tryFillUserCredentials();
      tryAutoLogin();
    });
  }

  getReemberMe() async {
    rememberMe =
        await SharedPreferencesHelper.getBool("myapp_remember_me");
    setState(() {
      rememberMe = rememberMe ?? false;
    });
  }

  tryFillUserCredentials() async {
    var username = await secureStorage.get("myapp_email");
    var password = await secureStorage.get("myapp_password");
    setState(() {
      _usernameController.text = username;
      _passwordController.text = password;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    hideSystemOverlay();
    setDisplayDimensions();
    return SwipeDetector(
        onSwipeDown: onSwipeDown,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: onScaffoldTap,
          child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  buildControlsLayer(),
                  buildPolicyLayer(),
                  buildVersionLayer()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  buildLogo(int inFlex) {
    return Flexible(
      flex: inFlex,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/myapp_logo.png',
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
      ),
    );
  }

  rememberMeChange(bool newValue) {
    setState(() {
      rememberMe = newValue;
    });
  }

  privacyPolicyTapped() {
    resetFocus();
    launch("https://www.myteam.se/policy.html");
  }

  void resetPasswordPressed() {
    resetFocus();
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResetPasswordPage()),
    );
  }

  clearUserCredentialTextfields() {
    setState(() {
      _usernameController.clear();
      _passwordController.clear();
    });
  }

  void loggaInPressed() async {
    resetFocus();
    SharedPreferencesHelper.setBool("myapp_remember_me", rememberMe);
    if (!rememberMe)
      deleteUserCredentials();
    else
      storeUserCredentials(_usernameController.text, _passwordController.text);
    var loginModel =
        new LoginModel(_usernameController.text, _passwordController.text);
    var response0 = await postLogin(loginModel);
    if (response0.statusCode == 200) {
      if (!rememberMe) clearUserCredentialTextfields();
      setState(() {
        loginResponse = "";
      });
      var loginToken = Token.fromJson(json.decode(response0.body));
      globals.loginToken = loginToken;
      var response1 = await getUserToken(loginToken.token);
      if (response1.statusCode == 200) {
        var userAndToken =
            UserAndTokenModel.fromJson(json.decode(response1.body));
        var userToken = new Token(token: userAndToken.token);
        var userModel = userAndToken.userModel;
        globals.userToken = userToken;
        globals.userModel = userModel;
        if (rememberMe) storeTokens(loginToken.token, userToken.token);
        // var fcmHelper = new FCMHelper();
        // fcmHelper.configureFCM(context);
        // fcmHelper.registerFCMToken(userModel);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
        );
      } else
        setState(() {
          loginResponse = "Fel uppstod vid inloggning.";
        });
    } else
      setState(() {
        loginResponse = "Felaktig email eller lösenord.";
      });
  }

  storeUserCredentials(String email, String password) {
    secureStorage.set("myapp_email", email);
    secureStorage.set("myapp_password", password);
  }

  storeTokens(String loginToken, String userToken) {
    secureStorage.set("myapp_login_token", loginToken);
    secureStorage.set("myapp_user_token", userToken);
  }

  deleteUserCredentials() {
    secureStorage.delete("myapp_email");
    secureStorage.delete("myapp_password");
    secureStorage.delete("myapp_login_token");
    secureStorage.delete("myapp_user_token");
  }

  Future<http.Response> postLogin(LoginModel loginModel) {
    String data = json.encode(loginModel);
    return http.post(
        Uri.parse(globals.apiBaseUrl + "authentication/authenticate_mobile"),
        body: data,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        });
  }

  Future<http.Response> postFCMToken(String data) {
    var userToken = globals.userToken.token;
    return http.post(Uri.parse(globals.apiBaseUrl + "/user/set_fcm_token"),
        body: data,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          "Authorization": "Bearer $userToken"
        });
  }

  Future<http.Response> getUserToken(String loginToken) {
    return http
        .get(Uri.parse(globals.apiBaseUrl + "user/get_by_token"), headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Authorization": "Bearer $loginToken"
    });
  }

  tryAutoLogin() async {
    var loginToken = await secureStorage.get("myapp_login_token");
    if (loginToken != null) autoLogin();
  }

  autoLogin() async {
    var loginToken = await secureStorage.get("myapp_login_token");
    var response = await getUserToken(loginToken);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var userAndToken = UserAndTokenModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      var userToken = new Token(token: userAndToken.token);
      var userModel = userAndToken.userModel;
      globals.userToken = userToken;
      globals.userModel = userModel;
      // var fcmHelper = new FCMHelper();
      // fcmHelper.configureFCM(context);
      // fcmHelper.registerFCMToken(userModel);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      );
    } else
      showMessageDialog(
          "Inloggningssessionen utgången", "Logga in igen med dina uppgifter.");
  }

  void showMessageDialog(String title, String body) {
    try {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: new Text(title),
              content: new Text(body),
            );
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  void usernameChange(String value) {
    print("");
  }

  void addKeyBoardListener() {
    keyboardVisibilityController = KeyboardVisibilityController();
    keyboardVisibilityController.onChange.listen(onKeyboardVisibilityChange);
  }

  Widget buildUsernameTextfieldAdaptedToKeyboard() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? buildKeyBoardVisibleUsernameTextfield()
        : buildKeyBoardHiddenUsernameTextfield();
  }

  Widget buildPasswordTextfieldAdaptedToKeyboard() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? buildKeyboardVisiblePasswordTextfield()
        : buildKeyboardHiddenPasswordTextfield();
  }

  Widget buildKeyBoardVisibleUsernameTextfield() {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 18,
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 8,
              child: TextField(
                  focusNode: emailFocus,
                  controller: _usernameController,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.none,
                  onChanged: usernameChange,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      height: 1,
                      fontSize: displayWidth * globals.textFieldFontSize0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
                    labelText: 'Epost',
                  ),
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none),
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyBoardHiddenUsernameTextfield() {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 8,
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 8,
              child: TextField(
                  focusNode: emailFocus,
                  controller: _usernameController,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.none,
                  onChanged: usernameChange,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      height: 1,
                      fontSize: displayWidth * globals.textFieldFontSize0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
                    labelText: 'Epost',
                  ),
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none),
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardVisiblePasswordTextfield() {
    return Flexible(
      flex: 18,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 8,
            child: TextField(
                focusNode: passwordFocus,
                maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.none,
                controller: _passwordController,
                autocorrect: false,
                style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1,
                    fontSize: displayWidth * globals.textFieldFontSize0),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  labelText: 'Lösenord',
                ),
                obscureText: true,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardHiddenPasswordTextfield() {
    return Flexible(
      flex: 8,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 8,
            child: TextField(
                focusNode: passwordFocus,
                maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.none,
                controller: _passwordController,
                autocorrect: false,
                style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1,
                    fontSize: displayWidth * globals.textFieldFontSize0),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  labelText: 'Lösenord',
                ),
                obscureText: true,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardAdaptedResponseForms() {
    return Expanded(
      flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 6 : 5,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 8,
            child: Container(
                child: Text("$loginResponse",
                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: displayWidth * globals.linkFontSize0,
                        color: Colors.red),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left)),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardAdaptedRememberMeForms() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? Container()
        : Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          "Kom ihåg mig",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: displayWidth * globals.linkFontSize0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Checkbox(
                          value: rememberMe,
                          onChanged: rememberMeChange,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardAdaptedIForgotPasswordLink() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? Container()
        : Flexible(
            flex: 5,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Text(
                        "Jag har glömt mitt lösenord",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            fontSize: displayWidth * 0.04),
                      ),
                      onTap: resetPasswordPressed,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  buildKeyboardAdaptedButtonBar() {
    return Flexible(
        flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 14 : 6,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(
              flex: 4,
            ),
            Expanded(
                flex: 15,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                          (states) => Color.fromRGBO(217, 217, 217, 1))),
                  child: Text(
                    'Logga in',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: displayWidth * globals.buttonFontSize0,
                        color: new Color.fromRGBO(54, 104, 129, 1.0)),
                  ),
                  onPressed: loggaInPressed,
                )),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 15,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                        (states) => Color.fromRGBO(217, 217, 217, 1))),
                child: Text(
                  'Avbryt',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: displayWidth * globals.buttonFontSize0,
                      color: new Color.fromRGBO(54, 104, 129, 1.0)),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  resetFocus();
                  _usernameController.clear();
                  _passwordController.clear();
                },
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 4,
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  void setDisplayDimensions() {
    if (displayWidth == 1) displayWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  }

  void onKeyboardVisibilityChange(bool visible) {
    setState(() {
      isKeyboardVisible = visible;
    });
  }

  hideSystemOverlay() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
  }

  void onScaffoldTap() {
    resetFocus();
  }

  void resetFocus() {
    try {
      if (emailFocus.hasFocus) emailFocus.unfocus();
      if (passwordFocus.hasFocus) passwordFocus.unfocus();
      if (passwordFocus.hasFocus || emailFocus.hasFocus)
        Focus.of(context).unfocus();
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  onSwipeDown() {
    resetFocus();
  }

  buildPolicyLink() {
    return InkWell(
      child: Text(
        "Sekretesspolicy",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: displayWidth * globals.linkFontSize0,
            color: Colors.blue,
            decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
      ),
      onTap: privacyPolicyTapped,
    );
  }

  buildVersionNr() {
    return Text(
      "Version 1.2.9",
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: displayWidth * globals.linkFontSize0, color: Colors.black),
    );
  }

  buildControlsLayer() {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 2 : 7),
          buildLogo(isKeyboardVisible ? 40 : 20),
          Spacer(flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 1 : 3),
          Flexible(
            flex: 10,
            child: Text(
              "Välkommen till My App",
              overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: displayWidth * globals.titleFontSIze0),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 7,
          ),
          buildUsernameTextfieldAdaptedToKeyboard(),
          Spacer(flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 4 : 2),
          buildPasswordTextfieldAdaptedToKeyboard(),
          isKeyboardVisible ? Spacer(flex: 2) : Container(),
          buildKeyboardAdaptedResponseForms(),
          buildKeyboardAdaptedRememberMeForms(),
          buildKeyboardAdaptedIForgotPasswordLink(),
          Spacer(flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 4 : 2),
          buildKeyboardAdaptedButtonBar(),
          Spacer(
            flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 2 : 10,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  buildPolicyLayer() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? Container()
        : Positioned(
            bottom: 10,
            left: 10,
            child: buildPolicyLink(),
          );
  }

  buildVersionLayer() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? Container()
        : Positioned(bottom: 10, right: 10, child: buildVersionNr());
  }
}
```

### pubspec.yaml:

```
name: myapp
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_messaging: ^11.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  path_provider_platform_interface: ^2.0.1
  platform: ^3.0.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^4.2.1
  swipedetector: ^1.2.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  firebase_core: ^1.0.4
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/myapp_logo.png
    - assets/myapp_logo.png
    - assets/logo_small.png
    - assets/green_smiley.png
    - assets/orange_smiley.png
    - assets/red_smiley.png
    - assets/horizontal_line.png
```

## Final thoughts and question

Why isn't the log in page rendered properly in the release build, but works in debug mode?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess there might be some rendering error which flutter release command doesn't show and it just builds the apk I did have the same issue and figured out that the problem was in my code only, just make sure you are using and following proper lints and flutter basics rules...

Comment: My 2 cents: you can connect you phone to the PC via USB and from cmd line you can run `flutter logs` to check what happens at runtime. This works even if your app runs in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Found Issue

I found the error now. The problem was how I used `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`. I first called the `setDisplayWidth()` method to get the display width and then assigned the value to the `dispayWidth` variable. But for some reason, this didn't work in release mode. The widgets were actually rendered, however, since the `setDisplayWidth()` call didn't work as I intended to, all text was set to a size between 0-1 pixels, which made it look like the text/widgets weren't rendered properly. Because you can see in my code in the question how I set all text size relative to the `displayWidth` variable. But the `displayWidth` variable always had the default value 1, which made the text
practically invisible.

To solve the issue described above, I removed the `displayWidth` variable completely and instead I fetch `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` directly in the build method everytime I need the display width. See my new code below.

## New Code (Solution)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';
// import 'package:inflecto/helpers/FCMHelper.dart';
import 'package:inflecto/helpers/SecureStorageHelper.dart';
import 'package:inflecto/helpers/SharedPreferencesHelper.dart';
import 'package:inflecto/models/LoginModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:inflecto/models/Token.dart';
import 'package:inflecto/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:inflecto/models/UserAndTokenModel.dart';
import 'package:inflecto/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:inflecto/pages/reset_password_page.dart';
import 'package:swipedetector/swipedetector.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

import '../home_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  String loginResponse = "";
  SecureStorageHelper secureStorage = new SecureStorageHelper();
  bool rememberMe = false;
  bool isKeyboardVisible = false;
  FocusNode emailFocus = new FocusNode();
  FocusNode passwordFocus = new FocusNode();
  KeyboardVisibilityController keyboardVisibilityController =
      new KeyboardVisibilityController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    init();
    delayedInit();
    super.initState();
  }

  init() {
    emailFocus = new FocusNode();
    passwordFocus = new FocusNode();
    rememberMe = false;
    addKeyBoardListener();
    secureStorage = new SecureStorageHelper();
  }

  delayedInit() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      await getReemberMe();
      await tryFillUserCredentials();
      await tryAutoLogin();
    });
  }

  getReemberMe() async {
    rememberMe =
        await SharedPreferencesHelper.getBool("hjarnkraft_remember_me") ??
            false;
    setState(() {
      rememberMe = rememberMe;
    });
  }

  tryFillUserCredentials() async {
    var username = await secureStorage.get("hjarnkraft_email");
    var password = await secureStorage.get("hjarnkraft_password");
    setState(() {
      _usernameController.text = username ?? "";
      _passwordController.text = password ?? "";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    hideSystemOverlay();
    return SwipeDetector(
        onSwipeDown: onSwipeDown,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: onScaffoldTap,
          child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  buildControlsLayer(),
                  buildPolicyLayer(),
                  buildVersionLayer()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  buildLogo(int inFlex) {
    return Flexible(
      flex: inFlex,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/hjarnkraft_logo.png',
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
      ),
    );
  }

  rememberMeChange(bool? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      rememberMe = newValue ?? false;
    });
  }

  privacyPolicyTapped() {
    resetFocus();
    launch("https://www.knowe.se/policy.html");
  }

  void resetPasswordPressed() {
    resetFocus();
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResetPasswordPage()),
    );
  }

  clearUserCredentialTextfields() {
    setState(() {
      _usernameController.clear();
      _passwordController.clear();
    });
  }

  void loggaInPressed() async {
    resetFocus();
    SharedPreferencesHelper.setBool("hjarnkraft_remember_me", rememberMe);
    if (!rememberMe)
      deleteUserCredentials();
    else
      storeUserCredentials(_usernameController.text, _passwordController.text);
    var loginModel =
        new LoginModel(_usernameController.text, _passwordController.text);
    var response0 = await postLogin(loginModel);
    if (response0.statusCode == 200) {
      if (!rememberMe) clearUserCredentialTextfields();
      setState(() {
        loginResponse = "";
      });
      var loginToken = Token.fromJson(json.decode(response0.body));
      globals.loginToken = loginToken;
      var response1 = await getUserToken(loginToken.token);
      if (response1.statusCode == 200) {
        var userAndToken =
            UserAndTokenModel.fromJson(json.decode(response1.body));
        var userToken = new Token(token: userAndToken.token);
        var userModel = userAndToken.userModel;
        globals.userToken = userToken;
        globals.userModel = userModel;
        if (rememberMe) storeTokens(loginToken.token, userToken.token);
        // var fcmHelper = new FCMHelper();
        // fcmHelper.configureFCM(context);
        // fcmHelper.registerFCMToken(userModel);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
        );
      } else
        setState(() {
          loginResponse = "Fel uppstod vid inloggning.";
        });
    } else
      setState(() {
        loginResponse = "Felaktig email eller lösenord.";
      });
  }

  storeUserCredentials(String email, String password) {
    secureStorage.set("hjarnkraft_email", email);
    secureStorage.set("hjarnkraft_password", password);
  }

  storeTokens(String loginToken, String userToken) {
    secureStorage.set("hjarnkraft_login_token", loginToken);
    secureStorage.set("hjarnkraft_user_token", userToken);
  }

  deleteUserCredentials() {
    secureStorage.delete("hjarnkraft_email");
    secureStorage.delete("hjarnkraft_password");
    secureStorage.delete("hjarnkraft_login_token");
    secureStorage.delete("hjarnkraft_user_token");
  }

  Future<http.Response> postLogin(LoginModel loginModel) {
    String data = json.encode(loginModel);
    return http.post(
        Uri.parse(globals.apiBaseUrl + "authentication/authenticate_mobile"),
        body: data,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        });
  }

  Future<http.Response> postFCMToken(String data) {
    var userToken = globals.userToken.token;
    return http.post(Uri.parse(globals.apiBaseUrl + "/user/set_fcm_token"),
        body: data,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          "Authorization": "Bearer $userToken"
        });
  }

  Future<http.Response> getUserToken(String? loginToken) {
    return http
        .get(Uri.parse(globals.apiBaseUrl + "user/get_by_token"), headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Authorization": "Bearer $loginToken"
    });
  }

  tryAutoLogin() async {
    var loginToken = await secureStorage.get("hjarnkraft_login_token");
    if (loginToken != null) autoLogin();
  }

  autoLogin() async {
    var loginToken = await secureStorage.get("hjarnkraft_login_token");
    var response = await getUserToken(loginToken);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var userAndToken = UserAndTokenModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      var userToken = new Token(token: userAndToken.token);
      var userModel = userAndToken.userModel;
      globals.userToken = userToken;
      globals.userModel = userModel;
      // var fcmHelper = new FCMHelper();
      // fcmHelper.configureFCM(context);
      // fcmHelper.registerFCMToken(userModel);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      );
    } else
      showMessageDialog(
          "Inloggningssessionen utgången", "Logga in igen med dina uppgifter.");
  }

  void showMessageDialog(String title, String body) {
    try {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: new Text(title),
              content: new Text(body),
            );
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  void usernameChange(String value) {
    print("");
  }

  void addKeyBoardListener() {
    keyboardVisibilityController = KeyboardVisibilityController();
    keyboardVisibilityController.onChange.listen(onKeyboardVisibilityChange);
  }

  Widget buildUsernameTextfieldAdaptedToKeyboard() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? buildKeyBoardVisibleUsernameTextfield()
        : buildKeyBoardHiddenUsernameTextfield();
  }

  Widget buildPasswordTextfieldAdaptedToKeyboard() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? buildKeyboardVisiblePasswordTextfield()
        : buildKeyboardHiddenPasswordTextfield();
  }

  Widget buildKeyBoardVisibleUsernameTextfield() {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 18,
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 8,
              child: TextField(
                  focusNode: emailFocus,
                  controller: _usernameController,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.none,
                  onChanged: usernameChange,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      height: 1,
                      fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                          globals.textFieldFontSize0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
                    labelText: 'Epost',
                  ),
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none),
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyBoardHiddenUsernameTextfield() {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 8,
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 8,
              child: TextField(
                  focusNode: emailFocus,
                  controller: _usernameController,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.none,
                  onChanged: usernameChange,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      height: 1,
                      fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                          globals.textFieldFontSize0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
                    labelText: 'Epost',
                  ),
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none),
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardVisiblePasswordTextfield() {
    return Flexible(
      flex: 18,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 8,
            child: TextField(
                focusNode: passwordFocus,
                maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.none,
                controller: _passwordController,
                autocorrect: false,
                style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1,
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                        globals.textFieldFontSize0),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  labelText: 'Lösenord',
                ),
                obscureText: true,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardHiddenPasswordTextfield() {
    return Flexible(
      flex: 8,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 8,
            child: TextField(
                focusNode: passwordFocus,
                maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.none,
                controller: _passwordController,
                autocorrect: false,
                style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1,
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                        globals.textFieldFontSize0),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  labelText: 'Lösenord',
                ),
                obscureText: true,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardAdaptedResponseForms() {
    return Expanded(
      flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 6 : 5,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 8,
            child: Container(
                child: Text("$loginResponse",
                    overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                            globals.linkFontSize0,
                        color: Colors.red),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left)),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardAdaptedRememberMeForms() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? Container()
        : Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          "Kom ihåg mig",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                  globals.linkFontSize0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Checkbox(
                          value: rememberMe,
                          onChanged: rememberMeChange,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  Widget buildKeyboardAdaptedIForgotPasswordLink() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? Container()
        : Flexible(
            flex: 5,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Text(
                        "Jag har glömt mitt lösenord",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
                      ),
                      onTap: resetPasswordPressed,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  buildKeyboardAdaptedButtonBar() {
    return Flexible(
        flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 14 : 6,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(
              flex: 4,
            ),
            Expanded(
                flex: 15,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                          (states) => Color.fromRGBO(217, 217, 217, 1))),
                  child: Text(
                    'Logga in',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                            globals.buttonFontSize0,
                        color: new Color.fromRGBO(54, 104, 129, 1.0)),
                  ),
                  onPressed: loggaInPressed,
                )),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 15,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                        (states) => Color.fromRGBO(217, 217, 217, 1))),
                child: Text(
                  'Avbryt',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                          globals.buttonFontSize0,
                      color: new Color.fromRGBO(54, 104, 129, 1.0)),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  resetFocus();
                  _usernameController.clear();
                  _passwordController.clear();
                },
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 4,
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  void onKeyboardVisibilityChange(bool visible) {
    setState(() {
      isKeyboardVisible = visible;
    });
  }

  hideSystemOverlay() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
  }

  void onScaffoldTap() {
    resetFocus();
  }

  void resetFocus() {
    try {
      if (emailFocus.hasFocus) emailFocus.unfocus();
      if (passwordFocus.hasFocus) passwordFocus.unfocus();
      if (passwordFocus.hasFocus || emailFocus.hasFocus)
        Focus.of(context).unfocus();
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  onSwipeDown() {
    resetFocus();
  }

  buildPolicyLink() {
    return InkWell(
      child: Text(
        "Sekretesspolicy",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * globals.linkFontSize0,
            color: Colors.blue,
            decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
      ),
      onTap: privacyPolicyTapped,
    );
  }

  buildVersionNr() {
    return Text(
      "Version 1.2.9",
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * globals.linkFontSize0,
          color: Colors.black),
    );
  }

  buildControlsLayer() {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 2 : 7),
          buildLogo(isKeyboardVisible ? 40 : 20),
          Spacer(flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 1 : 3),
          Flexible(
            flex: 10,
            child: Text(
              "Välkommen till Hjärnkraft",
              overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                      globals.titleFontSIze0),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 7,
          ),
          buildUsernameTextfieldAdaptedToKeyboard(),
          Spacer(flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 4 : 2),
          buildPasswordTextfieldAdaptedToKeyboard(),
          isKeyboardVisible ? Spacer(flex: 2) : Container(),
          buildKeyboardAdaptedResponseForms(),
          buildKeyboardAdaptedRememberMeForms(),
          buildKeyboardAdaptedIForgotPasswordLink(),
          Spacer(flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 4 : 2),
          buildKeyboardAdaptedButtonBar(),
          Spacer(
            flex: isKeyboardVisible ? 2 : 10,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  buildPolicyLayer() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? Container()
        : Positioned(
            bottom: 10,
            left: 10,
            child: buildPolicyLink(),
          );
  }

  buildVersionLayer() {
    return isKeyboardVisible
        ? Container()
        : Positioned(bottom: 10, right: 10, child: buildVersionNr());
  }
}
```

## Conclusion

Be careful with how you use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` in your apps and widgets. Always test the release version because it might behave totally differently compared to the debug version. I don't know why my first code didn't work honestly.

Answer (score 2):

It is possibly because there are errors (exceptions) when the rendering is running. Have you checked whether there is an exception? For example, if you are using error-reporting tools like Sentry, go to its webpage to see. If you do not have one, try to see logs. Or, setup error handling (e.g. simply print it) following the official guide: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors.

If you cannot find out any clues, try to setup error handling and put all logs here and I can try to see it.

---

**EDIT**

With more info, I can explain what happens.

```
  void setDisplayDimensions() {
    if (displayWidth == 1) displayWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  }

  void buildOtherPartsOfUI() {
   ...use displayWidth...
  }
```

This seems not to be a perfect way. If setDisplayDimensions is called **after** buildOtherPartsOfUI, the UI will be rendered with old width instead of the newly fetched one. It will only be updated when next `build` happens. However, even worse, you cannot control when the next build happens. (You can use `setState` to let Flutter know it should call `build` in the next frame; but since you did not, Flutter can call `build` later, or it can call `build` in 100 years later if UI does not change.)

Comment: I will take alook at the guide, thank you!

Comment: I posted my own answer now. However, your links were helpful because it was easier to find out that there were actually no exceptions thrown. You can read my own answer if you are curious about what the issue was. I will reward you with the bounty in 7 hours (it's disabled now) when I can.

Comment: @EggBender Happy to hear that - congratulations!

Comment: @EggBender I have updated my answer to explain the root cause - it is NOT because MediaQuery is bad ;)

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I think I understand it a bit better now at least.

Comment: @EggBender Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar implementation, which is getting screen display information early, calculating and storing the ratio to one static field. This static field is used to make the app responsive to the device's display.

And it works fine in **debug mode**, but the content is not rendered properly in **release mode**.

Screenshots as below:

| Debug Mode | Release Mode |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Debug Mode] | [image: Release Mode] |

---

### Root cause

In release mode, the app does not require to load all the debugging features, hence making lightweight apps load even faster.

As of Flutter 2.10.3, it is not able to get the proper display information early when the app is building. And if the value is stored and reused later, it will not work as intended.

### Solution (kind of hacky...)

I add one delay task before `runApp()`, like how we initialize Firebase in Flutter app.
This will reserve enough time for Flutter engine to finish its setup.

It also solves another issue for me. The splash screen only shows in a blink in release mode, and I want the user can see the logo properly.

#### Default main function to start the app:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

#### Solution - add delay task before `runApp()`:

```dart
void main() async {
  /* 
    * Additional function call to ensure widgets flutter binding is initialized,
    * but the issue still happens if no delay task below.
  */
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  /* 
    * This will make splash screen lasts for the duration of the delay task.
    * 300ms looks well for me, can adjust based on your preference.
  */
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**For detailed implementation, please refer to [this repository](https://github.com/yeejingt95/device_width_issue).**

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already answered but for me the problem was the Flexible component, i was using it wrong, if none of the another answers helps you, take a look at this component documentation and check if its ok on your project.

PS: on debug mode i no have problems, only on release mode.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. Widget works fine in debug mode but not showing up in release mode.
In my case problem has been solved by fixing `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget` warning.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33457961)