# Release build not shows some widgets in flutter, but debug build shows it in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mode

[This is debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XUgT.jpg)

[This is release mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI0rK.jpg)

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:no_balance/notification_api.dart';


import 'timer.dart';
import 'list.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService().initNotification();
  runApp(const MainPage());
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}


class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  title: const Text("No balance: only work"),
                  centerTitle: true,
                  bottom: const TabBar(
                    indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "TIME"),
                      Tab(text: "LIST")
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                body: const TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    TimerPage(),
                    ListPage()
                  ],
                ),
              )
          )
      );
}
```

timer.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';
import 'notification_api.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

class TimerPage extends StatefulWidget{
  const TimerPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TimerPageState createState() => _TimerPageState();
}

class _TimerPageState extends State<TimerPage>
{

  @override
  void initState(){
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    super.initState();
  }

  bool isPaused = true;
  int value = 1;
  static int TimeInSecond = 5;
  int MainTime = 5;
  double percent = 0.0;
  int h = 0, m = 0, s = 5;

  void UpdateTimeFunc() {
    List <String> arr = (timeInputTimeController.text).split(" ");
    if (arr.length == 3) {
      h = int.parse(arr[0]);
      m = int.parse(arr[1]);
      s = int.parse(arr[2]);
      if (arr.length == 3 && h >= 0 && m >= 0 && m < 60 && s >= 0 && s < 60){
        TimeInSecond = h * 3600 + m * 60 + s;
        MainTime = TimeInSecond;
        percent = 0;
        setState(() {
          h = TimeInSecond ~/ 3600;
          m = (TimeInSecond - h * 3600) ~/ 60;
          s = TimeInSecond % 60;
          ++value;
          isPaused = true;
        });
      }
      else {
        NotificationService().showNotification(id: 1, title: "ERROR", body: "Wrong time entry");
      }
    }
    else {
      NotificationService().showNotification(id: 1, title: "ERROR", body: "Wrong time entry");
    }
  }

  void _startCountDown() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (TimeInSecond > 0 && isPaused == false){
        setState((){
          if (TimeInSecond == 2){
            NotificationService().showNotification(id: 0, title: "TIME!!!", body: "Time is left");
          }
          TimeInSecond--;
          h = TimeInSecond ~/ 3600;
          m = (TimeInSecond - h * 3600) ~/ 60;
          s = TimeInSecond % 60;
        });
      }
      else{
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }


  // Timer handler functions: play, pause, stop
  void PlayFunc(){
    if (isPaused == true && TimeInSecond != 0){
      isPaused = false;
      _startCountDown();
    }
  }

  void PauseFunc(){
    setState((){
      isPaused = true;
    });
  }

  void StopFunc(){
    setState((){
      isPaused = true;
      TimeInSecond = 0;
      h = 0; m = 0; s = 0;
    });
  }



  TextEditingController timeInputTimeController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  CircularPercentIndicator(
                    circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                    percent: TimeInSecond/MainTime,
                    animation: true,
                    animateFromLastPercent: true,
                    radius: 140.0,
                    lineWidth: 20.0,
                    progressColor: Colors.red,
                    center: Text(
                        TimeInSecond == 0 ? 'Time is left' : "$h:$m:$s",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            fontSize: 60.0
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(70),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.red,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( //to set border radius to button
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: PlayFunc,
                        child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow)
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.red,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( //to set border radius to button
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: PauseFunc,
                        child: const Icon(Icons.pause)
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.red,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( //to set border radius to button
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: StopFunc,
                        child: const Icon(Icons.stop)
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: timeInputTimeController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        hintText: "Type by 'Space': 0 54 5 is 0:54:05",
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.red,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( //to set border radius to button
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => {UpdateTimeFunc()},
                        child: const Icon(Icons.send)
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

list.dart

```dart
// library no_balance.list;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

List<String> tasks = [];

class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
}


class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage>
{

  int value = 1;
  TextEditingController taskInputController = TextEditingController();


  Future<void> _getList () async
  {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final tasks = prefs.getStringList('tasks');
    setState(() {
      ++value;
    });
  }

  void UpdateData() async {
    if (taskInputController.text != "") {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      tasks.add(taskInputController.text);
      await prefs.remove('tasks');
      await prefs.setStringList('tasks', tasks);
      setState(() {
        ++value;
      });
    }
  }

  void RemoveElementFromStorage(int index) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    tasks.removeAt(index);
    final success = await prefs.remove('tasks');
    await prefs.setStringList('tasks', tasks);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _getList();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences sp) {
      var sharedPreferences = sp;
      tasks = sp.getStringList('tasks')!;
      setState(() {++value;});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body:Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              itemCount: tasks.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index)
              {
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(tasks[index]),
                    trailing: const Icon(Icons.restore_from_trash_rounded, size: 30,),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      // tasks.removeAt(index);
                      RemoveElementFromStorage(index);
                    });
                  }
                );
              },
            ),

            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                        controller: taskInputController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Enter your task",
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                          filled: true,
                        ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.red,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => {UpdateData()},
                        child: const Icon(Icons.send)
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I did the build using **flutter build apk --debug** and **flutter build apk --release**.

Program has another permissions:

*android:showWhenLocked="true"*

*android:turnScreenOn="true"*

Testing with phone on android 6.
Flutter and all packages updated to latest version.
Console doesn't output any errors.

[Dev tools screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLdXz.png)

How I can fix it?

Comment: There is some error that has been raised by flutter while executing. These can be found under run tab (bottom most) or via flutter DevTools. Please try to fix it, or share snippet of your code, so that we can try to help you out as well

Comment: please check flutter devtools logging; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4dCHbINmyk&t=200s

Answer (score 2):

is it showing "Incorrect use of parent data widget" in the console? If it is you are wrapping the wrong widgets inside the tree. Suppose you are using any expanded or flexible try to put that inside row or column.

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as yours, and I finally fixed it. It seems the problem is the widget is not properly initialised, so you have to wait or give some delay when you run your app in the main() function

Maybe this would help:

Instead of this:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService().initNotification();
  runApp(const MainPage());
}
```

You can have:

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService().initNotification();
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  runApp(const MainPage());
}
```

My answer is referring to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71614185/15188468

Hope this would help